# Como esperar una cierta cantidad de tiempo entre cada ejecucion de un metodo

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Toda a todos,

Tengo una aplicacion que consume varios servicios web. Lo que hace esta aplicacion que obtiene muchos usuarios y crea entradas en un archivo .csv para varios proyectos.

Me gustaria hacer la ejecucion para una cierta cantidad de usuarios, cada 100 o 200 usuarios la aplicacion espere unos 30 segundos y continue su ejecucion.

Que esto se realize hasta que se complete la ejecucion.

Quiero evitar la carga de Querys hacia la base de datos y evitar que el trafico se sature debido a que hago varios llamados web.

De que forma puedo hacer eso?

Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Aqui esta parte de mi codigo:

```
UserData[] userIds = GetUserID();
if (userIds.Length > 0)
{

    List<string> multiUserIDs = new List<string>();

    foreach (var userdata in userIds)
    {
        multiUserIDs.Add(userdata.List[0].ToString());
    }


    string testName = "test_";
    string outCsvFile = string.Format(@"D:\\TasksForAllProjects\\{0}.csv", testName + DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyyMMdd HHmms")); 
    String newLine = "";
    var stream = File.CreateText(outCsvFile);

    stream.WriteLine("ProjectName,UserFirstName,UserLastName,TaskStatus);

    string temp = "";

    var AllProjectIds = proj.ProjectID; //Esto viene de otra llamada hecha mas arriba

    string[] projectIDs = new string[] { AllProjectIds }; // all projects
    string singleUserID = "";
    string[] taskStatus = new string[] { "notcompleted" };  

    TaskEntry[] result = GetTasks(projectIDs, singleUserID, multiUserIDs.ToArray(),taskStatus); 

    newLine = string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\"",
                    item.ProjectTitle,
                    item.UserID,
                    status);
        //Creating a new file when new entries are found.
        stream.WriteLine(newLine);
}
stream.Close();
```

Veo que el problema podria de venir de la variable `multiUserIDs` la cual tiene la totalidad de los usuarios.

Entonces deberia ejecutar de una cantidad de usuarios que viene de esa variable.

Comment: pero son 200 o 300 usuario que lanzaran peticiones al servicio de forma concurrente ? porque no veo bueno que detengas un hilo de ejecucion en un entorno web. Se supone que la aplicaicon debe estar pensada para procesamiento concurrente sino algo estas diseñando de forma incorrecta

Comment: Hola si, lo que pasa que en total en todos los proyectos hablamos de unos 400,000 usuarios, si yo ejecuto la llamada la mayor parte del tiempo tengo un timeout o congela la base de datos, es por eso que busco de que sea mas eficiente mismo si se demora

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si estas generando un csv no lo realices de esa forma, usa una libreria como ser

[CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

entonces podras mapear los datos completos sin necesidad de recorrer registro por registro.

Entiendo que tienes una clase en la variable `result` en ese caso la exportacion es directa

```
var csv = new CsvWriter( textWriter );
csv.WriteRecords( result );
```

Es mas si analiza la documentacion podrias personalizar el mapping y genera el archivo en una sola operacion, de esta forma no tendrias que usar ninguna detencion del codigo.

**>>si yo ejecuto la llamada la mayor parte del tiempo tengo un timeout o congela la base de datos**

No veo como estas recuperando los registros, pero ese problema no es la generacion del csv sino como recuperas los datos, quizas debas evaluar usar un `DataReader`

Pero detener el codigo no me parece una buena alternativa.

Answer (score 9):

tienes que dormir el hilo:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
```

El parámetro que recibe está en Milisegundos.

De todas maneras hacer esto a veces no es buena idea, y tendrías que plantearte el porqué tienes que dormir la aplicación tanto tiempo. Si esto es algo que se va a mantener en el tiempo deberías considerar otro diseño.